# get true labels from keras generator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I want to use [`sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) to create a confusion matrix for a keras model.

After training a model I can use [`predict_generator(generator)`](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict_generator) to get predictions for a test dataset, which gives me `y_pred`. How can I get the corresponding true labels, `y_true` from a data generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`generator.classes` will give you observed values in sparse format. You probably need it in dense (i.e., one-hot encoded format). You could get that with:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(generator.classes)).to_dense()
```

NOTE though: you must set the generator's `shuffle` attribute to `False` before generating the predictions and fetching the observed classes, otherwise your predictions and observations will not line up!

Answer (score 1):

After creating a data generator, either your own or the built in [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class), use your trained model to make predictions:

```
true_labels = data_generator.classes
predictions = model.predict_generator(data_generator)
```

sklearn's confusion matrix expects a 1-d array of labels, so you have to convert your predictions using `np.argmax()`

```
y_true = true_labels
y_pred = np.array([np.argmax(x) for x in predictions])
```

Then you can use those variables directly in the `confusion_matrix` function

```
cm = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

And you can plot it using the example `plot_confusion_matrix()` function found here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html

[image]